# How to store a vector of objects of an abstract class which are given by std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class, stdvector

I got a loop in which i use a function returning std::unique_ptr to an object of an abstract class. I want to store these objects into a std::vector via push_back. But since the objects are of abstract type i get the following error:

```
error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type
```

for the line

```
  cells.push_back(std::move(*cell));
```

where cells is a `std::vector` of the abstract type and `cell` is of type

```
std::unique_ptr<AbstractType>&& cell
```

(I actually pass `cell` to a handler class)
I know that one can not instantiate an abstract type and as I'm understanding the std:move operator it need to instantiate the object somehow?

Can anybody help me how to manage the problem? Or should the function (not my part of the project) not return a unique pointer to an object of an abstract type?

Comment: Are we talking about a `vector<AbstractType>`? That won't work. Store a `vector<unique_ptr<AbstractType>>` instead.

Comment: You are right! I was blind, I changed it to `vector<unique_ptr<AbstractType>>` and now it works

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes:  +1 on your comment (that should be an answer).  You must read minds!

Comment: Why is `cell` an rvalue reference? That sounds wrong. Can we see more code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't store `AbstractType` elements directly on a `std::vector`. You can simply store the `unique_ptr`s themselves in a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractType>>` with `cells.push_back(std::move(cell))`.

Comment: The reason being that you are invoking the copy constructor, and thus trying to instantiate an abstract class.