# Why I can not use abstract class in std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have came from those questions:

- [Why can't we declare a std::vector<AbstractClass>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160920/why-cant-we-declare-a-stdvectorabstractclass)
- [abstract classes in std containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125669/abstract-classes-in-std-containers)
- [How to store a vector of objects of an abstract class which are given by std::unique_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203878/how-to-store-a-vector-of-objects-of-an-abstract-class-which-are-given-by-stdun)

They all suggested that I should use pointer or smart pointers instead.

As far as I know, Data are dynamically allocated in `std::vector` which means that there are pointers internally in the `std::vector`. So why I can not use abstract classes directly? why I have to use pointers(The one I specified) for pointers(the internally) in order to use abstract classes with `std::vector`. I know some features like `std::vector::resize` won't work. However, `std::vector::reserve` and `std::back_inserter` will solve the problem.

Comment: Did you read the comment under the answer to the third question you linked - "The reason being that you are invoking the copy constructor, and thus trying to instantiate an abstract class."

Comment: No I missed it.. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As far as I know, Data are dynamically allocated in std::vector which means that there is pointers internally in the `std::vector`

That's absolutely right. However, the pointer (actually, one of two pointers in the very common implementation) points to an array of identically-sized elements of type `T`, not to a single element of `T` or its subtype. Essentially, the pointer is used to represent an array, not to refer to a class or its subclass.

That is why you need an extra level of indirection - elements of an array `T[]` are not capable of storing subclasses of `T` without *object slicing*.

Answer (score 5):

> Data are dynamically allocated in `std::vector` which means that there is pointers internally in the `std::vector`

No, that's a misconception. `std::vector` allocates an array of instances internally, and you can't create an instance of an abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that memory for `std::vector` is allocated dynamically, the fact is that in `std::vector<T>` objects of type `T` are stored *as copies*. And you simply cannot copy abstract classes.

For example, if you have a base class `A`, a derived class `B`, and a `std::vector<A>`. Then, if you try to stored an object of type `B` in that vector, it will be copied and stored as an `A`. That is, it will be *spliced*.

```
class A {};
class B: public A {};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> as;
    B b;
    as.push_back(b); //<-- splice!!!
}
```

That, assuming that class `A` is copiable (and non-abstract). If it is abstract the compiler will save you the trouble and fail the declaration of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert something into a vector, the template has to first instantiate the class (since it uses the **copy constructor**). Since this is not possible with an abstract class, you can't do it!

[Source](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=801460)