# Dynamic cast c++ Inheritance Issue

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an issue with Dynamic cast  with inheritance.

I have Shape which is a base class and Rectangle which is a deviated class.

In my Rectangle.h file, I have the following

```
class Rectangle: public Shape
```

In my main class, I create a vector of Shape class named record

```
std::vector<Shape> record;
```

In my Shape.h file, I have the virtual function computeArea().

```
virtual double computeArea();
```

My Rectangle.h file contains the function double computeArea()

I am trying to dynamic cast the Shape into Rectangle to compute the area

```
for(int i=0; i < record.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << record[i].getName() <<endl;
        if(record[i].getName() == "Rectangle")
        {
            Rectangle& rectest = dynamic_cast<Rectangle&>(record[i]);
            cout << rectest.computeArea() << endl;
        }
    }
```

However,I got this error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast' what():  std::bad_cast Aborted"

Any one know what could be the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot store polymorphic objects in containers without making them pointers, regular or smart. There's lots of duplicates on this site explaining what's wrong (object slicing) and what needs to be done. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37911600/335858)

Comment: Hi there. Sorry for asking a duplicate question. I am pretty new in c++. Will take a look at the object slicing link above. Thanks!

Comment: to solve the problem of object slicing use pass by reference or by pointers not by value